# Set value in row to value in last row +1 only if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the format:

|  | Condition | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | 0 |
| 2 | False | 0 |
| 3 | True | 0 |
| 4 | True | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to update it such that the group number is one plus the previous group number only if the condition is true:

|  | Condition | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | 0 |
| 2 | False | 0 |
| 3 | True | 1 |
| 4 | True | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

What is the most pythonic way to do this? Is using a loop easiest, or is there a more efficient or readable way with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cumsum:

```
 s = df['Condition'].cumsum()
 df['Group'] = s - s.min()
```